# Python - Elasticsearch reindex

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Trying to use the `elasticsearch-py` python module to run a re-index. For testing purposes I want only a small number of documents to be processed. As per [docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.reindex) I had this:

```
es.reindex({
      "source": {
          "index": source_index},
      "dest": {"index": new_index}
    }, max_docs=10)
```

But that resulted in - `reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_docs'`

SO I tried -

```
es.reindex({
      "source": {
          "index": source_index,
          "max_docs": 10
      },
      "dest": {"index": new_index}
    })
```

Error: `TransportError(400, u'x_content_parse_exception', u'Unknown key for a VALUE_NUMBER in [max_docs].')`

Tried:

```
reindex = es.reindex(
  body = {
  "max_docs": 10,
  "source": { "index": source_index },
  "dest": { "index": new_index },
  }
)
```

Error: `TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'[reindex] unknown field [max_docs], parser not found')`

How do I use the `max_docs` while reindexing ? Looks like the docs are not clear

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can apply a query to the `source` to limit the number of transferred docs:

```py
es.reindex({
    "source": {
        "index": "source_index",
        "query": {
           # your query body...
        }
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "dest_index"
    }
})
```