# Unable to reindex Elastic Search index name

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am renaming Elastic Search Index using python package ElasticSearch. 'transcripts' is already an index. Following is the code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es_host = "https://localhost:9200"

password = "PASSWORD_STRING"

es_client = Elasticsearch(es_host,basic_auth=('elastic', password),verify_certs=False)

es_client.reindex(source='transcripts',dest='transcript_sent')
```

Getting following error:

```
BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', "[1:9] [reindex] dest doesn't support values of type: VALUE_STRING")
```

Comment: Can you try rather than `source and dest`,`source.index` and `dest.index`. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292088/python-elasticsearch-reindex

Comment: Tried 

`es_client.reindex({"source":{'index':'transcripts'},"dest":{'index':'transcript_sent'}})`

as well `es_client.reindex(source={'index':'transcripts'},dest={'index':'transcript_sent'})`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please also share the response of the changes and let me try to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
client.reindex(body={
  "source": {
      "index": "transcripts"},
  "dest": {"index": "transcript_sent"}
  })
```

Hope this helps!